# Raspbian WheezyのPythonをpyenvで2.7.9にアップグレードしたらsmbusが使えなくなった

Tags: python

お世話になります。

デフォルトインストールされていたPython 2.3.7の時にsmbusを https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smbus-cffi の手順に沿ってインストールしたときは、smbusを正常に使うことができたのですが、pyenv でPython 2.7.9にインストールしたら `ImportError: No module named smbus` と出るようになってしまいました。再度同じ手順でインストールしても同じエラーが出てしまいます。

こちらを（https://github.com/Azelphur/pyPushBullet）利用するとPythonをアップグレードするように警告が出てしまうので、それを出ないようにするためにどうしても2.7.9を入れたいのです。どうか知恵をお貸し頂けないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「同じ手順」という部分をもう少し詳しく書いたほうが回答がもらいやすいかもしれません。pyenv で2.7.9を有効にして pip で cffi と smbus-cffi をインストールしているのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「同じ手順」とは、WheezyにデフォルトでインストールされているPython2.3.7の時に
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smbus-cffiに従ってpip で cffi と smbus-cffi をインストールした手順という意味です。

現状はpyenv で2.7.9を有効にして pip で cffi と smbus-cffi をインストールしても、ImportError: No module named smbusとエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: もう少し詳しくというのは、その手順を詳しく書いてくださいということでした。わざわざ他のページを見に行くのは面倒ですし、そのページの内容をどこまでやったのか正確に把握する手段がありません。また、同じにしたつもりになっているだけで実際には手順に漏れがあるかもしれません。というわけで、`pip install cffi` など一行ずつ実行したコマンドを書くと問題点がわかりやすくなるかもしれません。

Answer (score -3):

```
apt-cache search python-smbus
```

を実行したところ、下記の2行が出ました。

```
python-smbus - Python bindings for Linux SMBus access through i2c-dev
pypy-smbus-cffi - This Python module allows SMBus access through the I2C /dev
```

2行目行頭が"pypi"でなく"pypy"になってますが、関係ありますか？

Comment: 普通に考えると関係ないです。もちろん、思いもかけない事が関係している場合もありますから、何か関係が疑われる理由があれば、追加でご説明いただければと思います。とりあえず他の初心者の方が混乱してもいけないと思いますので、私は削除に投票しますが、これに懲りず今後なにかありましたら、情報提供などよろしくお願い致します。